# Dual screen setup in Xorg

Tags: debian, multiple-monitors, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card, crunchbang

I have two Nvidia cards (an onboard and an added one), and a monitor connected to each one. Monitors are "on", at least the LEDs indicates that they are. But only the one connected to the onboard card display my desktop.
I cannot move windows to the other one, but the cursor is displayed (but changed, it becomes a black cross).

My xorg.conf is the following:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "extmod"
    Load  "record"
    Load  "dbe"
    Load  "dri"
    Load  "dri2"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option        "Protocol" "auto"
    Option        "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option        "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor1"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "SWcursor"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HWcursor"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "NoAccel"                # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ShadowFB"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VideoKey"               # <i>
        #Option     "WrappedFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "GLXVBlank"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"            # <str>
        #Option     "PageFlip"               # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "nouveau"
    BusID       "PCI:0:16:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "SWcursor"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HWcursor"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "NoAccel"                # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ShadowFB"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VideoKey"               # <i>
        #Option     "WrappedFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "GLXVBlank"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"            # <str>
        #Option     "PageFlip"               # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card1"
    Driver      "nouveau"
    BusID       "PCI:2:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen1"
    Device     "Card1"
    Monitor    "Monitor1"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

and my xorg log...

```
[     4.740] 
X.Org X Server 1.10.4
Release Date: 2011-08-19
[     4.741] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[     4.741] Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 i686 Debian
[     4.741] Current Operating System: Linux desktop 3.2.0-0.bpo.2-486 #1 Wed May 30 00:30:23 UTC 2012 i686
[     4.741] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-0.bpo.2-486 root=UUID=b053304a-ba19-4012-9e8d-af61ba9cd2b9 ro quiet splash
[     4.741] Build Date: 29 August 2011  12:12:25AM
[     4.741] xorg-server 2:1.10.4-1~bpo60+1 (Cyril Brulebois <kibi@debian.org>) 
[     4.741] Current version of pixman: 0.24.0
[     4.741]     Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[     4.741] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     4.741] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed May 30 20:18:58 2012
[     4.744] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[     4.744] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     4.745] (==) ServerLayout "X.org Configured"
[     4.745] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[     4.745] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[     4.747] (**) |   |-->Device "Card0"
[     4.747] (**) |-->Screen "Screen1" (1)
[     4.747] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor1"
[     4.747] (**) |   |-->Device "Card1"
[     4.747] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[     4.747] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[     4.748] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     4.748] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     4.753] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     4.753]     Entry deleted from font path.
[     4.756] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     4.756]     Entry deleted from font path.
[     4.756] (**) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType,
    built-ins,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType,
    built-ins
[     4.756] (**) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     4.756] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[     4.756] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[     4.756] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[     4.756] (II) Loader magic: 0x81fa6c0
[     4.756] (II) Module ABI versions:
[     4.756]     X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[     4.756]     X.Org Video Driver: 10.0
[     4.756]     X.Org XInput driver : 12.2
[     4.756]     X.Org Server Extension : 5.0
[     4.757] (--) PCI:*(0:0:16:0) 10de:07e1:1458:d000 rev 162, Mem @ 0xe2000000/16777216, 0xd0000000/268435456, 0xe6000000/16777216, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[     4.757] (--) PCI: (0:2:0:0) 10de:0390:1043:81f5 rev 161, Mem @ 0xe3000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xe4000000/16777216, I/O @ 0x0000b000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[     4.757] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[     4.757] (II) "extmod" will be loaded. This was enabled by default and also specified in the config file.
[     4.757] (II) "dbe" will be loaded. This was enabled by default and also specified in the config file.
[     4.757] (II) "glx" will be loaded. This was enabled by default and also specified in the config file.
[     4.757] (II) "record" will be loaded. This was enabled by default and also specified in the config file.
[     4.757] (II) "dri" will be loaded. This was enabled by default and also specified in the config file.
[     4.757] (II) "dri2" will be loaded. This was enabled by default and also specified in the config file.
[     4.757] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[     4.770] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
[     4.773] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.773]     compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     4.773]     Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[     4.773]     ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[     4.773] (II) Loading extension SELinux
[     4.773] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[     4.773] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[     4.773] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
[     4.773] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[     4.773] (II) Loading extension XVideo
[     4.773] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[     4.773] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
[     4.773] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[     4.774] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
[     4.776] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.776]     compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.13.0
[     4.776]     Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[     4.776]     ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[     4.776] (II) Loading extension RECORD
[     4.776] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[     4.776] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
[     4.777] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.777]     compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     4.777]     Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[     4.777]     ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[     4.777] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[     4.777] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[     4.777] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[     4.783] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.783]     compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     4.783]     ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[     4.783] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
[     4.783] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[     4.783] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[     4.785] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     4.785]     compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.2.0
[     4.785]     ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[     4.785] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[     4.785] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     4.785] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libglx.so
[     5.091] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[     5.091]     compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[     5.091]     Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[     5.091] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  275.36  Sun Oct 16 23:50:38 PDT 2011
[     5.091] (II) Loading extension GLX
[     5.091] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[     5.093] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[     5.096] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.096]     compiled for 1.10.3, module version = 0.0.16
[     5.096]     Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     5.096]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 10.0
[     5.098] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Thu Mar 24 02:13:12 2011 +1000
[     5.098] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[     5.098]     RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[     5.098]     RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[     5.098]     GeForce 256     (NV10)
[     5.098]     GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[     5.098]     GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[     5.098]     GeForce 3       (NV20)
[     5.098]     GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[     5.098]     GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[     5.098]     GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[     5.098]     GeForce 7       (G7x)
[     5.098]     GeForce 8       (G8x)
[     5.098]     GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[     5.098]     GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[     5.098] (++) using VT number 7

[     5.109] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[     5.968] drmOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID pci:0000:00:10.0
[     5.968] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[     5.968] drmOpenDevice: open result is 7, (OK)
[     5.968] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns 7
[     5.969] drmOpenByBusid: drmGetBusid reports pci:0000:00:10.0
[     5.969] (II) [drm] nouveau interface version: 0.0.16
[     5.969] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[     5.969] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[     5.969] drmOpenDevice: open result is 7, (OK)
[     5.969] drmOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID pci:0000:02:00.0
[     5.969] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[     5.969] drmOpenDevice: open result is 7, (OK)
[     5.969] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns 7
[     5.969] drmOpenByBusid: drmGetBusid reports pci:0000:00:10.0
[     5.969] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card1
[     5.969] drmOpenDevice: open result is 7, (OK)
[     5.969] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns 7
[     5.969] drmOpenByBusid: drmGetBusid reports pci:0000:02:00.0
[     5.969] (II) [drm] nouveau interface version: 0.0.16
[     5.969] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[     5.969] (II) Loading sub module "dri"
[     5.969] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[     5.969] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[     5.969] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.969]     compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     5.969]     ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[     5.969] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Loaded DRI module
[     5.969] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[     5.969] drmOpenDevice: open result is 8, (OK)
[     5.969] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[     5.969] drmOpenDevice: open result is 8, (OK)
[     5.969] drmOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID pci:0000:00:10.0
[     5.969] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[     5.969] drmOpenDevice: open result is 8, (OK)
[     5.969] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns 8
[     5.969] drmOpenByBusid: drmGetBusid reports pci:0000:00:10.0
[     5.969] (II) [drm] DRM interface version 1.4
[     5.969] (II) [drm] DRM open master succeeded.
[     5.969] (--) NOUVEAU(0): Chipset: "NVIDIA NV63"
[     5.969] (==) NOUVEAU(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[     5.969] (==) NOUVEAU(0): RGB weight 888
[     5.969] (==) NOUVEAU(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[     5.969] (==) NOUVEAU(0): Using HW cursor
[     5.969] (==) NOUVEAU(0): GLX sync to VBlank disabled.
[     5.969] (==) NOUVEAU(0): Page flipping enabled
[     6.146] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Output VGA-1 using monitor section Monitor0
[     6.168] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Output DVI-D-1 has no monitor section
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): EDID for output VGA-1
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Manufacturer: ZDS  Model: 7700  Serial#: 1031
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Year: 1999  Week: 8
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): EDID Version: 1.0
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Analog Display Input,  Input Voltage Level: 0.700/0.300 V
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Sync:  Separate  Composite
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 32  vert.: 24
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Gamma: 2.00
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): DPMS capabilities: StandBy Suspend Off; RGB/Color Display
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): redX: 0.625 redY: 0.340   greenX: 0.302 greenY: 0.600
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): blueX: 0.141 blueY: 0.065   whiteX: 0.281 whiteY: 0.311
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Supported established timings:
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): 720x400@70Hz
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): 640x480@60Hz
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): 800x600@60Hz
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): 800x600@75Hz
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): 1024x768@75Hz
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Supported standard timings:
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): #0: hsize: 640  vsize 480  refresh: 85  vid: 22833
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): #1: hsize: 800  vsize 600  refresh: 85  vid: 22853
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): #2: hsize: 1024  vsize 768  refresh: 85  vid: 22881
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): #3: hsize: 1280  vsize 1024  refresh: 60  vid: 32897
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Supported detailed timing:
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): clock: 55.0 MHz   Image Size:  320 x 240 mm
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): h_active: 640  h_sync: 672  h_sync_end 768 h_blank_end 864 h_border: 0
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): v_active: 480  v_sync: 488  v_sync_end 494 v_blanking: 530 v_border: 0
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Supported detailed timing:
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): clock: 67.5 MHz   Image Size:  320 x 240 mm
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): h_active: 800  h_sync: 840  h_sync_end 920 h_blank_end 1056 h_border: 0
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): v_active: 600  v_sync: 603  v_sync_end 607 v_blanking: 639 v_border: 0
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Supported detailed timing:
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): clock: 108.0 MHz   Image Size:  320 x 240 mm
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): h_active: 1280  h_sync: 1328  h_sync_end 1440 h_blank_end 1688 h_border: 0
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): v_active: 1024  v_sync: 1025  v_sync_end 1028 v_blanking: 1066 v_border: 0
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): EDID (in hex):
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0):     00ffffffffffff006893007707040000
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0):     080901000c201864e80632a0574d9924
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0):     10484fa1420031594559615981800101
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0):     0101010101017c1580e020e032102060
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0):     860040f0100000185e1a200031582720
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0):     2850340040f01000001e302a00985100
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0):     2a403070130040f01000001e00000000
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0):     00000000000000000000000000000078
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): EDID vendor "ZDS", prod id 30464
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): DDCModeFromDetailedTiming: Ignoring tiny 0x0 mode
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   55.00  640 672 768 864  480 488 494 530 -hsync -vsync (63.7 kHz)
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   67.50  800 840 920 1056  600 603 607 639 +hsync +vsync (63.9 kHz)
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz)
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz)
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz)
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz)
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz)
[     6.300] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz)
[     6.301] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   36.00  640 696 752 832  480 481 484 509 -hsync -vsync (43.3 kHz)
[     6.301] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   56.25  800 832 896 1048  600 601 604 631 +hsync +vsync (53.7 kHz)
[     6.301] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   94.50  1024 1072 1168 1376  768 769 772 808 +hsync +vsync (68.7 kHz)
[     6.301] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Printing probed modes for output VGA-1
[     6.301] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz)
[     6.301] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x85.0   94.50  1024 1072 1168 1376  768 769 772 808 +hsync +vsync (68.7 kHz)
[     6.301] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x75.1   78.80  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.1 kHz)
[     6.301] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x100.0   67.50  800 840 920 1056  600 603 607 639 +hsync +vsync (63.9 kHz)
[     6.301] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x85.1   56.25  800 832 896 1048  600 601 604 631 +hsync +vsync (53.7 kHz)
[     6.301] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x75.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz)
[     6.301] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz)
[     6.301] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x120.1   55.00  640 672 768 864  480 488 494 530 -hsync -vsync (63.7 kHz)
[     6.301] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x85.0   36.00  640 696 752 832  480 481 484 509 -hsync -vsync (43.3 kHz)
[     6.301] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x60.0   25.20  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz)
[     6.301] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "720x400"x70.1   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz)
[     6.321] (II) NOUVEAU(0): EDID for output DVI-D-1
[     6.321] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Output VGA-1 connected
[     6.321] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Output DVI-D-1 disconnected
[     6.321] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Using exact sizes for initial modes
[     6.321] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Output VGA-1 using initial mode 1024x768
[     6.321] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Using default gamma of (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) unless otherwise stated.
[     6.321] (--) NOUVEAU(0): Virtual size is 1024x768 (pitch 0)
[     6.321] (**) NOUVEAU(0):  Driver mode "1024x768": 94.5 MHz (scaled from 0.0 MHz), 68.7 kHz, 85.0 Hz
[     6.321] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x85.0   94.50  1024 1072 1168 1376  768 769 772 808 +hsync +vsync (68.7 kHz)
[     6.321] (**) NOUVEAU(0):  Driver mode "1024x768": 78.8 MHz (scaled from 0.0 MHz), 60.1 kHz, 75.1 Hz
[     6.321] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x75.1   78.80  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.1 kHz)
[     6.321] (**) NOUVEAU(0):  Driver mode "800x600": 67.5 MHz (scaled from 0.0 MHz), 63.9 kHz, 100.0 Hz
[     6.321] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x100.0   67.50  800 840 920 1056  600 603 607 639 +hsync +vsync (63.9 kHz)
[     6.321] (**) NOUVEAU(0):  Driver mode "800x600": 56.2 MHz (scaled from 0.0 MHz), 53.7 kHz, 85.1 Hz
[     6.321] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x85.1   56.25  800 832 896 1048  600 601 604 631 +hsync +vsync (53.7 kHz)
[     6.321] (**) NOUVEAU(0):  Driver mode "800x600": 49.5 MHz (scaled from 0.0 MHz), 46.9 kHz, 75.0 Hz
[     6.321] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x75.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz)
[     6.321] (**) NOUVEAU(0):  Driver mode "800x600": 40.0 MHz (scaled from 0.0 MHz), 37.9 kHz, 60.3 Hz
[     6.321] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz)
[     6.321] (**) NOUVEAU(0):  Driver mode "640x480": 55.0 MHz (scaled from 0.0 MHz), 63.7 kHz, 120.1 Hz
[     6.321] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x120.1   55.00  640 672 768 864  480 488 494 530 -hsync -vsync (63.7 kHz)
[     6.321] (**) NOUVEAU(0):  Driver mode "640x480": 36.0 MHz (scaled from 0.0 MHz), 43.3 kHz, 85.0 Hz
[     6.321] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x85.0   36.00  640 696 752 832  480 481 484 509 -hsync -vsync (43.3 kHz)
[     6.321] (**) NOUVEAU(0):  Driver mode "640x480": 25.2 MHz (scaled from 0.0 MHz), 31.5 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[     6.321] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "640x480"x60.0   25.20  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz)
[     6.321] (**) NOUVEAU(0):  Driver mode "720x400": 28.3 MHz (scaled from 0.0 MHz), 31.5 kHz, 70.1 Hz
[     6.321] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "720x400"x70.1   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz)
[     6.321] (**) NOUVEAU(0):  Driver mode "1280x1024": 108.0 MHz (scaled from 0.0 MHz), 64.0 kHz, 60.0 Hz
[     6.321] (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz)
[     6.321] (**) NOUVEAU(0): Display dimensions: (320, 240) mm
[     6.321] (**) NOUVEAU(0): DPI set to (81, 81)
[     6.321] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[     6.321] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[     6.323] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[     6.324] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     6.324]     compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     6.324]     ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     6.324] (II) Loading sub module "exa"
[     6.324] (II) LoadModule: "exa"
[     6.324] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libexa.so
[     6.325] (II) Module exa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     6.325]     compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 2.5.0
[     6.325]     ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 10.0
[     6.325] (II) Loading sub module "shadowfb"
[     6.325] (II) LoadModule: "shadowfb"
[     6.326] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libshadowfb.so
[     6.327] (II) Module shadowfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     6.327]     compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     6.327]     ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     6.327] (II) Loading sub module "dri"
[     6.327] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[     6.327] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[     6.327] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     6.327]     compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     6.327]     ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[     6.327] (II) NOUVEAU(1): Loaded DRI module
[     6.327] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[     6.327] drmOpenDevice: open result is 9, (OK)
[     6.327] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[     6.327] drmOpenDevice: open result is 9, (OK)
[     6.327] drmOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID pci:0000:02:00.0
[     6.327] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[     6.327] drmOpenDevice: open result is 9, (OK)
[     6.327] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns 9
[     6.327] drmOpenByBusid: Interface 1.4 failed, trying 1.1
[     6.327] drmOpenByBusid: drmGetBusid reports pci:0000:00:10.0
[     6.327] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card1
[     6.327] drmOpenDevice: open result is 9, (OK)
[     6.327] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns 9
[     6.327] drmOpenByBusid: drmGetBusid reports pci:0000:02:00.0
[     6.327] (II) [drm] DRM interface version 1.4
[     6.327] (II) [drm] DRM open master succeeded.
[     6.327] (--) NOUVEAU(1): Chipset: "NVIDIA NV4b"
[     6.327] (==) NOUVEAU(1): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[     6.327] (==) NOUVEAU(1): RGB weight 888
[     6.327] (==) NOUVEAU(1): Default visual is TrueColor
[     6.327] (==) NOUVEAU(1): Using HW cursor
[     6.327] (==) NOUVEAU(1): GLX sync to VBlank disabled.
[     6.327] (==) NOUVEAU(1): Page flipping enabled
[     6.412] (II) NOUVEAU(1): Output DVI-I-1 using monitor section Monitor1
[     6.642] (II) NOUVEAU(1): Output VGA-2 has no monitor section
[     6.696] (II) NOUVEAU(1): Output TV-1 has no monitor section
[     6.764] (II) NOUVEAU(1): EDID for output DVI-I-1
[     6.869] (II) NOUVEAU(1): EDID for output VGA-2
[     6.869] (II) NOUVEAU(1): Manufacturer: NEC  Model: 3bb0  Serial#: 16843009
```

I don't understand why I can't move windows to the other screen while I can with my cursor (and why is it modified?!)

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using multiple cards you need to use Xinerama mode.  There are lots of details here:

http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/MultiMonitorDesktop

Comment: Thanks! How can I check if it is installed/install it before enable it in my xorg.conf?

Answer (score 2):

I tried several variations of xorg.conf, but all failed.

This worked for me.
I created a file ~/.xsessionrc with this line in it...

```
xrandr --output DVI-D-2 --right-of DVI-D-1
```

The names DVI-D-2 and DVI-D-1 may be different on your system.
You can list them with

```
xrandr -q
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the NVIDIA drivers instead of nouveau?

if you do use the NVIDIA drivers, you can install nvidia-settings package which will give you a GUI config panel. You are looking for the setting called "TwinView"

Comment: I tried the NVIDIA drivers, but TwinView was disabled in the GUI config panel, and when I tried to set it manually in the xorg.conf, I just ended up with a crash of the server x.